# Android: keyboard hidden button

Tags: android, button, keyboard

I have two linearlayout firts one with four edit text and second one with a button:

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="65dp"  android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/l_fields"
        android:stretchColumns="*"  android:layout_weight="1">
        <TableRow android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <AutoCompleteTextView style="@style/orderDropDownWidth" android:layout_weight="5" android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:completionThreshold="1"
                    android:id="@+id/eo_article" android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"   >
            </AutoCompleteTextView>
            <EditText android:inputType="numberSigned" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/eo_sale" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"    android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true">   </EditText>
            <EditText android:inputType="numberSigned" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/eo_promo" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"></EditText>
            <EditText android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/eo_disc" android:layout_weight="1"
             android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayoutadd" android:layout_height="55dp" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"  android:gravity="right" android:layout_weight="1" >
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"  android:gravity="right" android:layout_weight="1" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent">                        
        <Button android:text="@string/LINE_ADD" android:id="@+id/eo_baddline" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:gravity="top" style="@style/orderlineButtonSalePromo"           ></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is teh result:
[image]

But when keyboard is show the button is hidde:

[image]

How can I force to display button when keyboard is open?

Answer (score 0):

You should set your linear layouts with in a scroll view...so if the elements are within the scrollview,when the keyboard is in use,the button will move to the top level of the keyboard

Comment: Sorry bu it does nor work. This code still does not work: <ScrollView >
   <TableLayout android:layout_weight="1">
       <TableRow android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <EditText >   </EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:orientation="horizontal" >
     <LinearLayout>              
      <Button ></Button>
     </LinearLayout>        
       </TableRow>
     </TableLayout>
 </ScrollView>